# When to keep the passive voice and when to remove it

Tags: creative-writing, tenses

This is something I wrote:

> The person *was* standing in the middle of the clearing, facing away from me. It
>   *was* a girl. She *was* wearing a red knit hat, a white sweater, an a gray plaid
>   skirt that reached right below the knee. What *was* she doing here,
>   alone? I looked up, and realized she *was* gazing at a huge ancient
>   tree. It *was* as thick and tall as a watch tower. Its branches resembled arms,
>   and the leaves *were* so few you could count them with your fingers.

As you can see, that paragraph is filled with the passive voice.

So I tried changing some into the active voice:

> The person *stood* in the middle of the clearing, facing away from me. It
>   *was* a girl. She *wore* a red knit hat, a white sweater, an a gray plaid
>   skirt that reached right below the knee. What *was* she doing here,
>   alone? I looked up, and realized she *gazed* at a huge ancient
>   tree. *As* thick and tall as a watch tower. Its branches resembled arms,
>   and the leaves *were* so few you could count them with your fingers.

Did that improve readability? When to keep the passive voice?

Comment: I suggest to look up what "passive tense" means. You are not using passive voice here.

Comment: "She was gazing at a tree" <-> "The tree was gazed by her"

Comment: I changed your text to reflect what you intended to ask (passive *voice*, not *past tense*), but @JohnSmithers is correct; none of these are passive voice. SF.'s answer below is the right one.

Comment: Yes, it's *continuous* - in your case [*past continuous*](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html). Usage - like in my answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clearing the confusion. For some reason, I thought the passive tense was the use "was/were" in a sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the language level: when you show a moment from a continuous, slow or unchanging process or state - showing that the process was in progress, or the state was such already when the observation began.

On writing level - purpose: when you want to induce the feeling of stillness, create image instead of action, describe state instead of activity. Also, similarly to passive voice, to instill the impression of helplessness, laziness or dependence: things are done to subject, subject is enduring/enjoying them. In this case though this is excellent usage for describing calm, constancy, peace.

Your first sentence was fine. *The person stood in the middle of the clearing* might imply "walked up to the middle of the clearing and stopped". *she gazed at a huge ancient tree* might be read as "turned her head to the tree and began gazing." The continuous tense leaves no doubts - the scene is very still. This creates a different, more eerie mood, an elusive feeling you lose when you chase after actions instead of painting the still image.